# Unable to retrieve entity from datastore created using IncompleteKey()

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I am using "cloud.google.com/go/datastore" to store, update, retrieve entities from datastore. Struct created by me is -

```
type TExp struct {
    Key        string   `json:"key" datastore:"key,noindex"`
    Value      string   `json:"value" datastore:"value,noindex"`
} 

type service struct {
DataLayer *datastore.Client
}
```

When I create id for this using datastore.IncompleteKey("TExp", nil), I am able to create entity and can see it in real datastore.

```
func (s service)addTExp(ctx context.Context, request interface{}) (interface{}, error) {

req := request.(*TExp)
var tExp []TExp
var tExp2 TExp
tExp2.Key   = req.Key
tExp2.Value =   req.Value

query := datastore.NewQuery("TExp").Filter("key =", req.Key).Namespace("AdLive")
keys, err := s.DataLayer.GetAll(ctx, query, &tExp)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf(ctx,"Error occurred while checking existence of key in kind")
}

if keys == nil {
log.Infof(ctx,"Keys: %v ", keys)
k := datastore.IncompleteKey("TExp", nil)
k.Namespace = "AdLive"
k.Kind = "TExp"

if _, err := s.DataLayer.Put(ctx, k, &tExp2); err != nil {
    return nil, marvin.NewJSONStatusResponse(
        "could not add TExp in DS",
        http.StatusBadRequest,
    )} 
   }
   return "OK",nil
}
```

Problem is before creating any entity, I want to ensure that any entity with same Key value doesn't exist in kind of that datastore already. To do this, first of all I am trying to check existence using GetAll method than if keys are nil, I want to call datastore.Put to add new entity. However, in each case(even for already present entities in Datastore), "keys" variable always get nil value.

```
keys, err := s.DataLayer.GetAll(ctx, query, &tExp)
```

Therefore, multiple entities get created with same key value in datastore. I am not able to find out how can I fix this issue in golang.

Note:- in datastore entities have structure

["Name/ID automatically generated by Datastore on calling IncompleteKey method", Key, Value].

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to fetch a specific entity, you should use [Get](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Client.Get) instead of GetAll, as Get is strongly consistent, and GetAll is not.

Second, since you are doing a Put with an incomplete key, your will never have a conflict on the new entity that you are only adding to your Datastore.  It seems you want to be using a [transaction](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Client.NewTransaction) to both Get & Put an entity with the complete key that is passed into your function.

Comment: Hi @JimMorrison, First of all I want to check if there is any entity with same key value (not datastore's Id) exist or not, if not than I want to create new entity with given key and value field's value whose ID should be in numeric form and generated by datastore itself so that in case of update it can track this id.

Comment: My problem resolved after removing noindex from struct fields